# Excel 2007: Move the connection of an existing pivot table from a data connection to an Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I've created a workbook that has a pivot table in it that has the data sourced from an external connection.

Now I'm trying to expand the functionality of it, and want to switch it to an Excel table, because a bunch of other pivots are going to be using the same data and I don't want each one to pull it individually.

In 2003, this was possible by right-clicking the table, selecting "PivotTable Wizard", and then working backwards till you came to the "Select source" screen.

Is it possible to do this in 2007 without deleting and recreating?  I want to avoid that, because things tend to get names confused, and I don't want to have to recreate my calculated fields.  When I click "Change Data Source" on the Data section of PivotTable Tools -> Options, the "Excel Range" option is greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colleague told me:

"...The 'old' PivotTable wizard still exists in Excel 2007 but to use it you will either need to customize the Quick Access Toolbar to add the button 'PivotTable and PivotChart Wizard' from the 'Commands Not in Ribbon' or 'All Commands' category, or alternatively you can use the Excel 2003 keyboard shortcut sequence Alt-D-P to launch the wizard."